# Connection pool and max_connection relation

Tags: c#, mysql, multithreading

I am using MySQL Database and have a C# app which has parallel threads running queries. When connection pooling is enabled as per MySQL Workbench 3-5 connection threads are continuously utilized in the pool(most of them are sleeping). When connection pooling is disabled at most 1 connection thread is created and killed quickly.

Now my question is when connection pooling is enabled it creates 3-5 continuous connection threads per running C# app. So if the max_connection setting in MySQL is 151 I would be able to run only 30 instances of my C# app, right?

Also if I disable connection pooling at the expense of performance I would be able to run more than 151 instances of my C# app as few C# app would be generating queries in parallel. Am I right in this assumption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running through a Web Server (Apache, Tomcat, IIS, etc), you are at the mercy of the number of threads it might run.  (Apache has `MaxClients`.)

A single connection for all actions is the 'normal' way to write a program.  But you have 3-5 "threads", each with its own connection?  If so, yes, you are limited to about 30 Web Server threads (or standalone invocations of your program).

`max_connections` can be increased (by changing my.cnf and restarting).  2000 is high, but not unreasonable.

The problem comes when you have more than a few dozen *connections* actually *doing something*, as opposed to "Sleep". (see `SHOW PROCESSLIST;`)

MySQL connections are rather rapid; "pooling" has other issues, so it does not necessarily do more good than harm.  A connection has "state", including @variables, tmp tables, etc, that need to be reset whenever you ask for a connection and it comes from a "pool".

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. Also I have one more doubt and that is I have different connection strings and between them the only variation is the connection timeout property. Is this the cause of 3-5 Connection threads per instance of C# app?

As I have only 2 C# thread running in background which Sleep for 5 secs and only then generate queries. So I presume this is not a reason why 3-5 MySQL connection threads need to be created.

Comment: Sounds right.  Consider creating a singleton object (or some appropriate pattern) which contains the MySQL connection, lazily created.  Before each sql query, ask the object to for the connection.  That will let you avoid the "wasted" 5 seconds.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your point can you be a little more elaborate?

Comment: If you are not into OO stuff, then simply make a subroutine that has a static value.  The sub returns the static if set, else connects to the db and stores the handle in the static, and returns it.  Then call that sub just before each SQL query.